# Counting recursive function calls which are a multiple of k in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, ackermann

The assignment was to create a program that computes the Ackermann equation using recursion, which I successfully did. Part of the assignment says:

*"The function should print the number of recursive function calls which are multiple of k. Set k = 100 for
values of n; m <= 3, and k = 1; 000; 000 for all other values. Your program should also print the total number
of function calls made."*

The *ackermann* function is supposed to print out the number of function calls and recursive functions calls, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function to compute the end result ackermann equation
int ackermann (int n, int m)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        result = m + 1;

    } else if (m == 0)
    {
        result = ackermann(n - 1, 1);

    } else
    {
        result = ackermann(n - 1, ackermann(n, m - 1));
    }

    return result;
}

//main function
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char ans = 'y';
    int m, n, result;

    printf("\n\n------Ackermann Function------");

    while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y') {
        printf("\nPlease enter n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        printf("\nPlease enter m: ");
        scanf("%d", &m);

        result = ackermann(n, m);

        printf("\nResult: %d", result);

        printf("\n\nDo you want to go again? ");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a global variable, incrementing its value on each call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static int count = 0;

int func() 
{
  count ++
  // do your work
  // recursive call
}
```

Make static variable which will keep the total number of calls made to functions.

And in this case you don't have to make `count` as global making it local static into function is enough because static variable retains it's value as `static` has file scope.

Comment: i understand that, but what I don't understand is how the function should print out the number of recursive function calls which are a multiple of k.

Comment: As far as I understood, You can apply some logic here for multiple of `k` like  `if(count % k == 0) actual_count++;` then you have the `actual_count` variable which keeps the total number of that function calls. Because `count` keeps track of all function calls now just check it and increment the other variable `actual_count` which is also `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable, incrementing its value on each call:

```
int calls_count = 0;

...

int ackermann (int n, int m)
{
    ++calls_count;
...
```